# How to create a custom view for any chart from DGCharts?

Tags: ios-charts

I am using [danielgindi / DGCharts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library and can i somehow create a custom circle view for scatter chart instead of default one?

I want to achieve something like this

```
let dataSet = ScatterChartDataSet(entries: entries)
dataSet.valueFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11.0, weight: .semibold)
dataSet.label = nil
dataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
dataSet.setScatterShape(.custom(CustomUIView here))
```